# Tool-tip: not showing correctly using a Dark theme

Tags: css, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm using: *JDK 1.8.0.71*, *IntelliJ*, *CSS(for the themes)*, *Win7x64*.

I have an issue with my `tool-tips` but only for the `buttons`(or at least only there discovered). In my program, when I switch from one theme to another the tool-tips look like this:

[image: dark]
[image: bright]

As you can see the button tool-tip for the **dark theme** is very obscure.
I did not styled the tool-tips so far, so I don't know where is taking that from.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried these tags already:

```
visibility: visible;
-fx-background-color: red;
-fx-fill: red;
-fx-text-fill: red;
-fx-color: red;
-fx-opacity: 1.0;
```

For:

```
.tooltip {
.tooltip .label {
.tooltip .text {
.tooltip:hover {
.tooltip:hover .text {
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
```

- The `hover` is the only one that seems to change the text, but of course I have to hover over the tooltip, which takes just an instant then it disappears.
- The `background` changes perfectly, what I need is the text/label of the tooltip to change

Comment: Transparency is set only for borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, for future references if anyone come across a similar issue.

My problem was solved applying this in my CSS file:

```
.button .tooltip .text {
    -fx-fill: #a3acaf;
}
```

Use whatever colour you need; in my case I had a dark theme.